# $f\in C^{0}[-L,L]$ with period $2L$ and $\sum n(|a_{n}|+|b_{n}|)<\infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in C^{0}[-L,L]$ be a function with period $2L$. And let be $\{a_{n}\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $\{b_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ their coefficients. Assume that

$$\sum n(|a_{n}|+|b_{n}|)<\infty$$

Prove that $f\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and that Fourier's series of $f'$ converges uniformly to $f'$.

This question is from my homework and I having a hard time with it. If you just prove that $f$ is differentiable is a good help.

Comment: Show some work please. For example, show first that the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: Hint: The series converges uniformly. The derivative series converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truncated Fourier series
$$
             S_n^f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+a_1\cos(x)+b_1\sin(x)+\cdots+a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)
$$
converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test because, by assumption, one has the uniform estimate:
$$
               |S_n^f(x)| \le \frac{|a_0|}{2}+|a_1|+|b_1|+\cdots+|a_n|+|b|_n|
$$
Similarly, the series of derivatives $(S_n^{f})'(x)$ also converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test. Then $S_n^f$ converges uniforly to $f$. If $(S_n^f)'$ converges uniformly to $g$, $g$ must be continuous, and the equation
$$
        S_n^f(x)=S_n^f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}(S_n^f)'(t)dt
$$
has the limiting form
$$
          f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt.
$$
Hence $f$ is continuously differentiable, and the series $(S_n^f)'$ converges uniformly to $f'=g$.